What's the origin of "π-C" or "Drake modified pi" network for impedance matching / antenna tuner?
This is a history question.

This type of antenna tuner included the Drake MN-4, MN-4C, MN-7, MN-2000, MN-2700, Kenwood AT120, AT130, AT200, AT230, Yaesu FC-707, FC-757AT (Automated pi-C match), Tokyo HY-Power HC-150, DAIWA CNW-218, CNW-518, CNW-818, Comet CAT-10, and various Mizuho kits. However, this type of matching network seems to have disappeared thereafter, largely replaced by T-network tuners (which are not better but cheaper).
Questions:

Who started using this topology for load-matching purposes? Did anyone use before Drake MN-4 and Kenwood AT200?

Who named this pi-C or π-C network? In amateur literature, this type of network is rarely mentioned, but when it gets mentioned, it is often described as an extension of a pi-network (although that is not a very good way to describe how it operates).


I'd save how this works, how best to build it, what advantages/disadvantages, etc., for another day and perhaps for an article.
UPDATE/NOTES:
It seems that in the US, "Drake modified pi network" was the most commonly used description. The term π-C network appeared in some English text (e.g., user reviews), but that appeared far more often in Japanese text.
